# Linear convergence with Newton method multiple root

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, newton-raphson, sequence-of-function

I've a function $f \in C^{3}(\mathbb{R})$ with $f(\alpha)=f'(\alpha)=0$ and $f''(\alpha) \neq 0 $ and I'm trying to proove that the Newton's method has a linear convergence and that my sequence is well defined. Since $f$ has a multiple root, I can write $f(x)=(x-\alpha)^{2}g(x).$
We have for the Newton method $$x_{n+1}= x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}.$$ Hence
$$ |x_{n+1}-\alpha| =\left| \frac{g(x_n)+(x_n-\alpha)g'(x_n)}{2g(x_n)+(x_n-\alpha)g'(x_n)} \right||x_n-\alpha|$$
I want to find $k<1$ (where $k$ does not depend on $n$), with $$ |x_{n+1}-\alpha|\leq k|x_n-\alpha|.$$ How can I do it?

Comment: The $k$ will depend on the exact order of the root (2,3,...), so you should specify what that is.

Comment: the order of the root is 2

Comment: In that case I would not bother to introduce $g$ and would instead write $f(x_n)/f'(x_n)=\frac{\frac{1}{2} f''(\alpha)(x_n-\alpha)^2+o(x_n-\alpha)^2}{f''(\alpha)(x_n-\alpha)+o(x_n-\alpha)}=\frac{\frac{1}{2} (x_n-\alpha)+o(x_n-\alpha)}{1+o(1)}=\frac{1}{2} (x_n-\alpha)+o(x_n-\alpha)$.

Comment: Well, I need to prove that there exist an interval $J_{\delta}=]\alpha-\delta,\alpha+\delta[$ where the sequence $x_n$ is well defined for any $n$ for $x_0 \in J_{\delta}$

Comment: This same line of estimation achieves that, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $g(α)\ne 0$ you can find an interval around $α$ where
$$
\left|\frac{g'(x)(x-α)}{g(x)}\right|<\frac13
$$
Then on this interval the fraction that has to be bounded is smaller than
$$
\frac{1+\frac13}{2-\frac13}=\frac45.
$$
By making the first bound smaller towards $0$, you decrease also the second towards $\frac12$.